# How can I add an article to my Scopus id, that is already associated with another author's profile id

Tags: publications, scopus

One of my articles shows on other author's Scopus id. How can I claim that article for my Scopus id?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your profile page.
2. Click on "Edit profile".
3. You will be redirected to the "Author Feedback Wizard", where one category is called "Review documents".
   [image]
4. Scroll down and click on "Search missing documents".
5. Find your paper and confirm - if you cannot find it, perhaps make sure that the publication is indeed eligible to be indexed in Scopus.

You could also try to link your profile to your ORCID, to see if that helps.